# $this->email->send(); error is on send function

Tags: php, codeigniter

Email is sending but still showing error message just want to remove error msg code is working properly

```
    public function search()
        {
            $post=$this->input->post();
            $To['To'] = $post['to'];
                if(!empty($post)){
                $post['check_in']=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($post['check_in']));
                $post['check_out']=date('d-m-Y',strtotime($post['check_out']));
                $this->load->library('email');
                $config['protocol'] = "sendmail";
                $config['smtp_crypto'] = "ssl";
                $config['smtp_host'] = "mail.flightsworld.co.uk";
                $config['smtp_port'] = "587";
                $config['smtp_user'] = "info@flightsworld.co.uk"; 
                $config['smtp_pass'] = "";
                $config['charset'] = "utf-8";
                $config['mailtype'] = "html";
                $config['newline'] = "\r\n";

                $this->email->initialize($config);

                $message="<h1>Flights Enquiry (Flights World)</h1></br>";
                $message.="Phone: ".$post['phone']."<br>";
                $message.="Email: ".$post['email']."<br>";
                $message.="From: ".$post['from']."<br>";
                $message.="To: ".$post['to']."<br>";
                $message.="Check In: ".$post['check_in']."<br>";
                $message.="Check Out: ".$post['check_out']."<br>";
                $message.="No of Passengers: ".$post['no_of_pass']."<br>";
                $message.="<br><br>Thank You";

                $this->email->from("info@flightsworld.co.uk"); // change it to yours
                $this->email->to('flightsworld@outlook.com');// change it to yours
                // $this->email->to('salmansidd17@gmail.com');// change it to yours
                $this->email->subject("Flights world Enquiry");
                $this->email->message($message);
                $this->email->send();
                $this->load->view('site/search', $To);



            }
        }
```

email is sending but still showing error on send function

```
File: /home/p9j6x14w0twe/public_html/application/controllers/Site.php
Line: 70
Function: send this the error
```

Comment: where did you load `èmail` library?

Comment: What email library do you use? What does line 70 of Site.php contain? Please also read how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example here https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: _“File: /home/p9j6x14w0twe/public_html/application/controllers/Site.php Line: 70 Function: send this the error”_ - PHP doesn’t talk like that, it doesn’t say “Function: send this the error”. Quote the exact error message verbatim.

Comment: What do you have on Line 70 of Site.php?

Comment: Error is on $this->email->send

Comment: Email is sending properly bu

Comment: but still showing this error

Comment: $this->email->send(); is on line no 70

Comment: Error is on send function and i wrote it like this "this is the error"